# Python split using multiple characters in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Original List :

```
['ValueA : 123', 'Source: 10.01, Port: 101, Destination: 10.10', 'ValueB: 4,5,6']
```

I want to split the value which has multiple ":" and the results should look something like below:

```
['ValueA : 123', 'Source: 10.01', 'Port: 101', 'Destination: 10.10', 'ValueB: 4,5,6']
```

Note: This will not always be the second string. This could be anywhere in the list. Basically looking to split a value in the list which has Source, Post and Destination in the same list value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to split every element in your list, and merge those lists by adding them using `sum()`:

```
>>> L = ['ValueA : 123', 'Destination: 10.01, Port: 101, Destination: 10.10', 'ValueB: 456']
>>> L = sum(
    (
        # Split only if condition is met
        element.split(", ") if all(word in element for word in ["Source", "Port", "Destination"]) else [element]
        for element in L
    ),
    start=[],
)
>>> L
```

Notice the keyword argument used in `sum(..., start=[])`. By default, `sum()` starts with `start=0` because it's commonly used to add numerical values. In this case, we're using `sum()` to add lists, but `0+[]` would raise an exception. This is why we must change the start value to a list, an empty list.

Comment: It will not always be the middle string unfortunately.

Comment: Some of the other values will also have "," But I just need to split the list item which has Source, port and destination words.

Comment: what does start[] empty list do ?

Comment: `sum()` usually starts with `start=0` because it's commonly used to add numerical values. In this case, we're using `sum()` to add lists, but `0+[]` will raise an exception. This is why we must change the start value to a list, an empty list.